# .NET Core Tag Helper - Delay rendering of tag helpers in content of another tag helper when calling GetChildContentAsync

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, tag-helpers

I am creating a tag helper to render a table using an IEnumerable as the data source. I am using tokens with the property name in the data object that the tag helper will replace with the actual value from the data. This works fine; however, I am running into a problem when I try to use values from the data object as a parameter of another tag helper. For example, let's say I want to have an anchor tag helper in the content of my tag helper like so.

```
<a asp-action="SomeAction" asp-controller="MyController" asp-route-id="{{ValueFromDataObject}}">Link Text</a>
```

In my tag helper, I am calling GetChildContentAsync() to get the contents of the tag and I am looking for any tokens and replacing them with the appropriate data. The problem is the anchor tag helper gets rendered when I call GetChildContentAsync() with the token value. I have tried to override the anchor tag helper and set the order to run after my table tag helper, but that didn't fix it because I believe the render method is called when you call GetChildContentAsync(). Is there any way to get the contents of the child tag, manipulate it, and then render it?

I am really stuck on this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible that other tag helper allready has modified the content you can use the following to make sure you get the correct content:

```
var content = output.Content.IsModified ?
                output.Content.GetContent() :
                (await output.GetChildContentAsync()).GetContent();
```

then "pushing" changes (will also set Content.IsModified to true for future tag helpers to know):

```
output.Content.SetHtmlContent(content);
```